# Simple way to UPDATE an item using ASP .Net Core API controller and POSTMAN

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, http-put

With this simple way to make use of the PUT verb to update an item using ASP.Net Core 2.2 and Postman, I created a model as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

a controller method as follows:

```
// PUT: api/PutProduct/5
[HttpPut("api/[action]/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutProduct(Guid id, Product Product)
{
    if (id != Product.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _context.Entry(Product).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ProductExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    // return NoContent();
    return AcceptedAtAction("GetProduct", new { id = Product.Id, name = Product.Name }, Product);
}
```

then a JSON body as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Product (Edited)"
}
```

Now when I click on Postman PUT method it returns a 202 status, but instead of updating the "name" field with the new value it clears it.

if I add [FromBody] as below, it returns 400 Error (bad request):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PutProduct(Guid id, [FromBody] Product Product)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Is your controller decorated with `[ApiController]`? If I'm reading this correctly a 400 is the expected response because you're not passing an id in your postman request.

Comment: @k3davis I am passing an id in the url, and I don't need [ApiController] decoration since I specified that in the method route.

Answer (score 4):

In the first example the id populates the model's id from the route and not the name. Which is why it gets past the bad request check and name will be cleared as it was not populated.

In the second example you send a body that does not include an `id` which fails your validation check.

If using `[FromBody]` in this case you will need to include the id in the JSON payload.

```
{
    "id": "{Guid_here}",
    "name": "Product (Edited)"
}
```

otherwise you need to rethink the design/flow of the action

You should consider checking the model state of the data using `ModelState.IsValid` to ensure that it is valid.

First update model with data anotations

```
public class Product {
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

And check the state in the action.

```
[HttpPut("api/[action]/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutProduct(Guid id, [FromBody]Product Product) {

    if (id != Product.Id) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Id", "Invalid Id");
    }

    if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Entry(Product).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    } catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) {
        if (!ProductExists(id)) {
            return NotFound();
        } else {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return AcceptedAtAction("GetProduct", new { id = Product.Id, name = Product.Name }, Product);
}
```

Additionally you can update the model with annotations about where to bind the data from.

For example

```
public class Product {
    [Required]
    [FromRoute] //<--
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

Note the added attributes.

and send the original payload

```
{
    "name": "Product (Edited)"
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: You're right, since I was focusing on the first method I used [FromBody] and omitted to add "id" in the JSON payload, I've tried it now and it works. Have you please an idea about how to update name when using id from the route ?

Comment: @Sami-L included some options.

Comment: if I use [FromRoute("id")] in the model it will say: FromRouteAttribute doesn't contain a constructor that takes 1 argument.

Comment: @Sami-L hold on let me recheck that

Comment: @Sami-L ok remove that. I was thinking about a previous version.

Comment: I have tried the second option, but could not get it to work, I still get empty name, and when I add your error code I get ModelStateDictionary doesn't contain a definition for AddError.

Comment: I works only with one method, not the second, it needs [FromBody] supplied at Controller level and id specified in the json payload.